# I am trying to retrieve json file through backbone.js in my html document

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to retrieve `json` file through `backbone.js`(mvc) in my html document.
However, my json file contain nested objects. I don't know how to go for it.

```
    {"groups" :[

    {

    "NAME": "Languages", 

    "TYPE": "CATEGORY",  

    "ID": "language-support", 

    "PACKAGE_LIST": [

    {

            "NAME":"authconfig-gtk",

            "STATUS":"compulsory",

            "DESCRIPTION":"abc" 

    }

,

    {

            "NAME":"gnome-disk-utility", 

            "STATUS":"optional",

            "DESCRIPTION":"xyz"

    }    

    ]

    }

,        



 {

        "NAME": "Desktop Environments", 

        "TYPE": "CATEGORY",

        "ID": "desktops", 

        "PACKAGE_LIST": [

             {

            "NAME":"authconfig-gtk",

            "STATUS":"compulsory",

            "DESCRIPTION":"abc" 

            }

,


            {    

            "NAME": "gnome-disk-utility", 

            "STATUS":"optional",

            "DESCRIPTION":"xyz"

            }             

        ]

    }

    ]

    }
```

Comment: read this tutorial before moving further. Its a pretty simple one for any beginner.  
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an answer on how to deal with nested JSON, nested Backbone.Models and Collections, I wrote (a rather long-winded) explanation of the types of options you have.

This MIGHT be helpful for you.

[Parsing Nested Backbone Models and Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350218/cast-initialize-submodels-of-a-backbone-model/12354034#12354034)